# Combine two dates to one integer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I'm using SAP Data Service and I need to combine YYYYMMDDYYYYMMDD to int field where first YYYYMMDD is 1st day of month (and year) and next YYYYMMDD is same years and month last date.
On input I have year and month fields with int data type.

This one works if target field is in varchar data type. Whet i change to target field int, result is NULL because ||. Need some better suggestion.

```
cast(to_char( to_date( Excel2.Year|| lpad(Excel2.Month, 2, '0') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'int')
||
cast(to_char( last_date( to_date( Excel2.Year|| lpad(Excel2.Month, 2, '0') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'int')
```

Comment: that is Oracle syntax, why is this tagged with `TSQL`? and not `Oracle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are experiencing is overflowed when you are trying to fit 2014010120140101(YYYMMDDYYYMMDD) into INT Data-type. In t-sql we have BIGINT that can handle this string, if Oracle has a similar data type then please substitute INT with BIGINT

```
DECLARE @variable INT
SELECT @variable = '2014010120140101'

SELECT @variable
```

**ERROR:

The conversion of the varchar value '2014010120140101' overflowed an int column.: DECLARE @variable INT SELECT @variable = '2014010120140101' SELECT @variable**

```
DECLARE @variable BIGINT
SELECT @variable = '2014010120140101'

SELECT @variable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2014
DECLARE @Month INT = 08
DECLARE @Prefix DATETIME = CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(5))+'-'+CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(5))+'-'+'01'

DECLARE @LastDate VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@Prefix))),DATEADD(mm,1,@Prefix)),103),2))
DECLARE @Suffix DATETIME = CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(5))+'-'+CAST(@MONTH AS VARCHAR(5))+'-'+@LastDate
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Prefix,112)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Suffix,112)
```